# The argument type 'Stream<User?>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream<User>?'

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I wanted to use firebase authentication using Streams, however i am getting the above error on line `stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),`. I have tried **onAuthStateChange()** that is also not working.

```
class LandingPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return StreamBuilder<User>(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<User> snapshot) {
          if(snapshot.hasData) {
            print("data exists");
            return First();
          }
          else {
            return SignIn();
          }
        },
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for [authStateChanges](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/authStateChanges.html) you'll see that it returns a `Stream<User?>`. So your `StreamBuilder` should also be of `User?` instead of `User`:

```
return StreamBuilder<User?>(
  ...
```

Comment: Thank you a lot that is a perfect answer for this.